# Permitting A Path Parameter Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So I am starting to get a handle on `permit` (new to rails, and of course, rails 4).

When I pass a parameter through the path eg `form_for(@comment, :url => post_comments_path(@post.id))`

The log shows that it is being passed in this format:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"UKBczLBwbh/AF2XSTlWmPJcFEcgTSXA9PBE6VP6sD4k=", 
"user"=>{"first_name"=>"Jim Friner", "email"=>"jfriner@gmail.com"}, "comment"=>{"content"=>"Hey dudez"},
"commit"=>"Create Comment", "post_id"=>"1"}
```

As you can see Post Id is not wrapped by user or comment. It is not a hash within a hash.
Most of the tutorials, and answers I have found on how to use permit, assume it is form submitted and thus within either `user` or `comment`. They suggest the following:

`params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :email)`

However in this case, there is nothing to put for require, so I guess my question is, do I just ommit require and it should work Or do I do something like this:

`params.require(:post_id).permit(:post_id)`

or just

`params.permit(:post_id)`

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Strong parameters in Rails 4 is the replacement for `attr_accessible`, so is not meant for filtering all parameters, just those submitted by form to stop models from having certain attributes set.

In this case, the `post_id` parameter is used for routing, so you could filter it via a `before_action` but you cannot use strong parameters to do this.

Comment: Yea, you should be able to access it wherever needed. The problem will happen only with mass assignment, so you will need to use permit there.